# Typed array in QTScript

Tags: javascript, qtscript, typedarray

I have a javascript library that reads and writes C++ style data in binary format from/to a file. To do that, I use typed arrays (float32array,arraybuffer...).

I need to port this library to QtScript. QTScript is supposedly compliant with ECMA-262 which defines typed array, but I can't manage to make it work.

Does anybody have tried that ?